# Can the text of a Button be set directly in the ember View definition

Tags: ember.js

```
<button class="ember-view delete-tier-view">Click Me</button>
```

Can be done using

```
{{#view RateEditor.DeleteTierView}}Click Me{{/view}}
```

Is it possible in any latest version of ember to define the text in view definition and just use it like this

```
{{view RateEditor.DeleteTierView}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want static text, you can do just this:

```
RateEditor.DeleteTierView = Ember.View.extend({
  //...
  template: function () {
    return "Click Me";
  }
  //...
});
```

If you want text bound to a property on view, try this:

```
RateEditor.DeleteTierView = Ember.View.extend({
  //...
  text: "Click Me",
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.text}}")
  //...
});
```

EDIT:

Or you can define a template with `{{view.text}}` inside and set that under `templateName` property, like in  the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use a component!

But a simple answer for your question:
yes! use templateName on the View, and define the handlebars template.

Handlebars/HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-cool-template">
    TEST
</script>
```

JS:

```
RateEditor = {};
RateEditor.TestView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'my-cool-template'
});
```

Usage:

```
{{view RateEditor.TestView}}
```

Comment: I know there is a template. But I just want to use the `view-name.js` nothing else.